# Прозрачная текстура фигуры

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Как я могу сделать текстуру фигуры прозрачной? (Например, куб или цилиндр).

Сейчас я пытаюсь реализовать это так:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 1f);
glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f);
//Cube code
```

Это работает не совсем правильно, текстуры становятся более светлыми, но я не вижу объекты которые находятся за ними.

Как я могу сделать прозрачность, при которой будет видно что находится за объектом?

Comment: Для правильной работы прозрачности необходимо рисовать фигуры в порядке их приближения к зрителю, т.е. сначало рисуете фоновую фигуру, затем полупрозрачную которая ее перекрывает.

Comment: Или использовать алгоритмы семейства OIT ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency )